# Gulpfile changes css but doesnt save it

Tags: php, gulp, browser-sync, postcss

I'm trying to create a gulpfile that works with scss and php.

All went well, but i tested it by changing an h1 from red to yellow. Browsersync kicked in. H1 was now yellow. Changed it to green. And it turned green. Yay! It works.

But when i change a php file, all css changed are gone. Even when i delete my style.css file, it doenst work 100%. Its like it caches the css?! I dont know where to look for the solution on this one.

Can anyone help me?

This is my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
connect = require('gulp-connect-php'),
plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
rename = require('gulp-rename');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
cache = require('gulp-cache');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
connect.server({}, function () {
    browserSync({
        proxy: 'raak.test'
    });
  });
});

gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
    browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('images', function () {
  gulp.src('src/img/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true})))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/img/'));
});

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    var processors = [
       autoprefixer,
       cssnano
];

gulp.src(['src/css/style.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber({
        errorHandler: function (error) {
            console.log(error.message);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(postcss(processors))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('assets/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function () {
    gulp.watch("**/*.scss", ['styles']);
    gulp.watch("**/*.php", ['bs-reload']);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Its like it caches the css

Have you investigated this? I'd make a comment but my frickin points suck. If you go into dev tools (right click 'inspect') in chrome you can do a hard-reload by holding refresh and clicking the last option. This will clear any chance of a cache. Also if you have a service worker or are using indexeddb this may happen. Usually everyone developes in incognito mode to avoid this happening in the first place! Hope this helps :D

Comment: You know that feeling. When you have an issue, cant find the solution. And after waiting to long to ask around you throw it out their and pray that someone can fix it..

Well It was just a cache issue.. Thx for your help!